# Create a OneNote Page Without a Section

Tags: microsoft-onenote

Is it possible to create a Page in OneNote without it being in a section? I would like to make a Notebook only have a single entry? Do I always need to create a Section and a Page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, at least one section is needed. This is because of the data/file structure of OneNote. Microsoft is currently looking into changing this but I don't expect such a chenge to arrice soon because of compatibility issues with existing data.